# Angular-binding for 2 or more variables

Tags: angular, typescript

This example will only save the `unit`-object:

```
<select id="unit" name="unit" #unit="ngModel" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="iu.unit" (change)="onDropdownChangeUnit($event)">
                  <option *ngFor="let i of UI_Units" [ngValue]="i">{{i.name}}</option>
                </select>
```

The object will look like this: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgpAp.jpg).

I would like to have the `unit`-object and the `unitID` written back to the object in the `foreach`-loop + loading the initial-value loaded from it's `unitID`.

How to do it ?

**Updated:**

The [object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgpAp.jpg) is delivered from the backend without `unit`, but with the `unitId`, `unit` for example will be delivered over `UI_Units`.

A) I want the initial value loaded from `iu.unitId` (preselect) => `i`(`unit`) (if possible)

B) But when the user clicks another `i`(`unit`), `iu.unitId` and `iu.unit` should be changed

Hope this is more clear.

Comment: can you explain more of your problem?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda , updated

Answer (score 0):

Update inside html page as `[(ngModel)]="iu"` and `(change)="onDropdownChangeUnit(iu)"`

```
<select id="unit" name="unit" #unit="ngModel" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="iu" (change)="onDropdownChangeUnit(iu)">
     <option *ngFor="let i of UI_Units" [ngValue]="i">{{i.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And check inside the component page as below

```
iu:any;
onDropdownChangeUnit(item){
   console.log(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make following changes:

**component.html**

```
<select id="unit" name="unit"  class="form-control"  (change)="onDropdownChangeUnit($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let i of UI_Units" [value]="i?.id">{{i?.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**component.ts**

```
onDropdownChangeUnit($event){
  let id = $event.target.value;
  this.ui['unit'] = this.UI_Units.find((x) => x._id.toString() === id.toString());
}
```

Comment: I get something like "...Unexpected token ?, expected identifier or keyword...". Using Angular 8

Comment: @StartingAgain updated my answer  there was a typo here `[value]="i.?id"` should have been `[value]="i?.id"`

Comment: what does the `?` mean ?

Comment: @StartingAgain google  safe navigation operator `?`

Comment: Requirements changed, openend a separate post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076351/initially-loading-of-an-existing-option-fails