# Initially loading of an existing option fails

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

The initially loading (of an existing `iu.unit`) fails:

```
 <select id="unit" name="unit" #unit="ngModel" class="form-control" 
     [(ngModel)]="iu.unit" (change)="onDropdownChangeUnit(rec,iu)">
     <option *ngFor="let i of UI_Units" [ngValue]="i">{{i.name}}</option>
 </select>
```

It shows me all `unit`'s from `UI_Units`, but it doesn't show the initial value of `iu.unit`.

What did I d wrong ?

**Updated**

Structure, I go with a `foreach` over all `ingridientUnit => iu`, try to assign it with it's initial value.

But when the user wants to change that - `UI_Units => coming from backend(asp.net Core)` - it should be reassigned to `iu.unit`.

```
export class Recipe{

    id: string;

    ingridientUnit: IngridientUnit[] // iu

    // ...
}


export class IngridientUnit {

    id: string;

    unit: Unit[]

    // ...
}

export class Unit {

    id: string;
    name: string;

    // ...
}
```

Fetching from server:

```
 getUnits(filter: ServerRequest) {
    return this._http.get(this.myAppUrl + 'Unit/GetUnits' + '?' + this.toQueryString(filter))
        .pipe(map((res: Unit[]) => { return res; }));
}
```

Comment: Can you share your component.ts code?

Comment: The value stored in `iu.unit`must be === to one of the values in UI_Units. It must be one of those objects. Not another object that has the same properties.

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `select` only shows its children `option`s in the dropdown.

Following that reason, `iu.unit` must be in `UI_Units` or nothing will be selected by default and the option of `iu.unit` will not appear in the list.

We can check [Angular Forms' code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/select_control_value_accessor.ts#L134) on this, I'd like to direct you focus to line 134 `writeValue` and line 178 `_getOptionId`,

```
writeValue(value: any): void {
  this.value = value;
  const id: string|null = this._getOptionId(value);
  // excerpt only
}

_getOptionId(value: any): string|null {
  for (const id of Array.from(this._optionMap.keys())) {
    if (this._compareWith(this._optionMap.get(id), value)) return id;
  }
  return null;
}
```

`writeValue` is called when a value is passed into the element with `ngModel`, the value is then looked up in a map containing all the child options. If an option representing the value (in your case `iu.unit`) isn't found, nothing meaningful will happen.

Most importantly, the option would not appear by default under the select element, it will appear only when it's explicitly included in your template.

I've created [a working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruqxfq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) of what you're trying to accomplish, note that `iu.unit` is an element in the array `UI_Units`. That's how [its comparison algorithm work](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8c33f915293deab3ca5cd700e38ffed06bf81692/packages/core/src/util/comparison.ts#L13).

Comment: Can I use another control(angular-material, ng-bootstrap, ...) ,where I can achieve this ?

Comment: `<option *ngFor="let i of UI_Units.append(iu.unit)"` ... you mean like this, even this would work, the `unit` will be a duplicate in this list ?

Comment: Does `iu.unit` already exist in `IU_Units`? Can you provide a stackblitz example?

Comment: I preapared a Stacklitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsulhn?file=src/app/hello.component.ts , is that ok, or you need more informations ?

Comment: @StartingAgain https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dlwaoa?file=src/app/hello.component.ts Note I've only changed how `iu.unit` is initialized, as stated above in my reply, to be selected, it must be strictly equal to one of the option's value.

Comment: thank you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sj4m9x?file=src/app/hello.component.ts I am getting the values from the backend, async. Now on the view, there is only the same value, that is displayed. View = same value. Runtime=objects are different. Is there anything, I should take care of ?